# Improper convergence of this integral?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, improper-integrals

$$ \int_1^{\infty} \left\langle t\right\rangle\dfrac{\cos\left(t\right) - \sin\left(t\right)}{t^2}\,dt $$

where $\left\langle t\right\rangle$ is the rationale part of $t$.

I would like to use the improper integral comparison test with $ \dfrac 2{t^2} $, but I have no reason to think the integral is positive.  How can I evaluate if this function is integrable in the improper sense?  Thank you.

Comment: Two hints: $\langle t \rangle < 1$ and absolute convergence implies conditional convergence!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't worry about $\cos t - \sin t$, because
$$
\left|\langle t\rangle \frac{\cos t - \sin t}{t^2}\right| \le \frac{2}{t^2}
$$
and so we can apply [absolute convergence of improper integral](http://www.sosmath.com/calculus/improper/absconv/absconv.html).

Comment: Makes sense, didn't think of that.  Thank you!